# Can I access the internal MongoDB and ActiveMQ used by OpenShift Origin (and is this a good idea)?

Tags: mongodb, activemq-classic, paas, openshift-origin

In order to do its internal processing (management of nodes and gears and such) OpenShift Origin runs its own MongoDB and ActiveMQ services. This is in addition and completely separated from anything your applications may install for there own needs.

Can I access these internal services from my own applications? And is this a good idea? A use-case would be to facilitate communication *between* my applications.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed.

I'm not sure what specifically you have in mind, but there are quickstarts for a number of middlewares that you can run as OpenShift applications.